# Simulate repository subversion externals to git

Tags: git, svn, externals

I develop webprojects using subversion and I want to move to git. I have a lib folder (php files), a js folder (js files) and for each webproject a different directory (e.g project1) which has  the lib folder and js folder as externals. That way I have one copy of js files and php lib files in my repository. If I change a file in my project folder marked as external the change propagates to all projects and to the library folder. How can I simulate this behaviour on git?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6681459/23118

Comment: I have tried submodules, but I cant simulate exactly the externals behavior. Maybe I missed something. I don't understand the first four lines in the answer of the above question which refers to revisions and hashes.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for Git submodules.

Have a look here for more information:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules